What would happen if a Facehugger infected a Predator?
What would happen if a Facehugger infected a Predator?
I think since Facehuggers can infect anything, the Predators shouldn't be a long shot. So maybe it would have similarities to both races.

If I remember correctly this happened in a couple of the movies.

Also the video games and books.

I don't have time to write up an originally-sourced answer, but you're looking for Predalien.

Since you've tagged this with [tag:alien-vs.-predator], I can only assume you've watched that film?

When a mummy alien and a daddy predator love each other very much, there's a special hug that they do...

I don't understand the downvotes on this question. The question, although having room for improvement, and being something that happens several times within the canon, it's perfectly fair to ask for an answer. Not everyone has to be up to date with the whole canon, this site is precisely built on that premise. Also, the user who asks is new on the site, and this type of behaviour could very well discourage him/her from come back and make more questions. Please, be gentle with people asking fair questions and try to answer even if it's something pretty obvious

@DavidW your comment could perfectly fit a valid answer for this question. Just elaborate it a bit if you have time and post it like an answer.

@Bardo I didn't downvote, but I do think that a question that can be answered by watching the film that the question has been tagged with, or even just reading its plot summary on Wikipedia, has not been researched enough.

I haven't bothered watching more than the first "Predator" movie due to boredom. But I encountered a novel (Alan Dean Forster - a prolific author frequently doing novelisations of movies, with permission) set in the AVP-universe, where the normal reaction of a Predator on being impregnated by a Face-hugger was to suicide before the face-hugger had time to grow into viability.
"It's the only responsible thing to do", or words to that effect.
